# Why is my responsive CSS not working in this code?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following HTML code:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

    <body style="background-image:url('images/background-website-web-blue.jpg');background-size: 100% 100%;background-attachment:fixed;">
    <div class="content1" style="background-color: rgb(52,129,162,0.8); box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);" >
        <div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
            <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: transparent;"></div>
                <p style="color: white ; font-family: 'Roboto Slab',Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 40px; font-weight: 700;" >dockdockdock</p>
                <p style="color: white ; font-family: 'Roboto Slab',Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 25px; font-weight: 400; font-style: italic;">dockdcokdock</p> 
                <p style="color: white ; font-family: 'Roboto Slab',Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 40px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 52px;" >DUck duck duck duck <i style="color: red; font-weight: 700;">60 Hari</i> Bergabung Di Ecourse Ini</p>
                <br><br><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  p{
    font-size:5px;
  }
}
```

But why don't the `<p>` tags change into size 5px when media 600px or smaller?

And if I put the `<p>` tags above `<div>` it's working

Answer (score 2):

Because the [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of inline style is ranked much higher then just CSS

If you want your css for mobile to work with given HTML you need to add `!important` like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  p {
    font-size: 5px !important;
  }
}
```

Then it will work.

But to be honest, we should never use `!important`. That can be achieved easily in this case just move all your inline styles from HTML to the top of the CSS file

Working example with `!important`  https://jsfiddle.net/nvzupxb0/

Working example with CSS only https://jsfiddle.net/nvzupxb0/2/

**Notes on the CSS only solution**

1. had to add some classes on `<p>` tags because your markup didn't allow me to use `:nth-child()` pseudo selectors
2. removed the `<br>` tags from the last (.third) p tag because line brakes can be achieved with CSS padding-bottom. giving the advantage of changing the padding-height via CSS for mobile devices!

Answer (score 1):

Just move you inline css which is given in p tag to external css file or you can write !important like this -

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    p{
      font-size:5px !important;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a media query and make the paragraph with 5px !important.

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
p{
  font-size: 5px !important;
}
```

}